# Deserialize runtime created class

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I'm triying to deserialize a runtime created type with C# and JSON.net but it throws a resolve type exception.

I have an empty BaseElement class from where all the runtime created types inherit, all the types are guaranteed to be created before the deserialization process and I'm using the TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All setting for serialization and deserialization.

The process of creating the classes is this (reduced to an example):

```
        AssemblyName asmName = new AssemblyName();
        asmName.Name = "RaspElementTypes";
        AssemblyBuilder asmBuild = Thread.GetDomain().DefineDynamicAssembly(asmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);

        ModuleBuilder modBuild = asmBuild.DefineDynamicModule("TypeModule", "RaspElementTypes.dll");   

        TypeBuilder tb = modBuild.DefineType("ClassInfo", TypeAttributes.Class, typeof(BaseElement));

        //Add properties, functions, etc

        Type finalType =  tb.CreateType();
        var item = (finalType)Activator.CreateInstance(tType);
```

And the serialization / deserialization is like this:

```
        //Data is a BaseElement[] array with the ClassInfo instances

        //Serialize

        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All };
        string res = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data, Formatting.Indented, settings);

        //Deserialize

        var deser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <BaseElement[]>(res, settings);
```

The exact error is this:

*An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Additional information: Error resolving type specified in JSON 'ClassInfo, RaspElementTypes'. Path '$values[0].$type'.*

Any idea on how to deserialize the runtime created types?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, found it, just needed to create a SerializationBinder to supply the correct types.

In mi exact case the binder looks like this:

```
class binder : SerializationBinder
{
    Type[] types;
    public binder(Type[] Types)
    {
        types = Types;
    }

    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        if(assemblyName == "RaspElements")
        {

            var type = types.Where(t => t.Name == typeName).FirstOrDefault();

            if (type != null)
                return type;

        }
        return Type.GetType(typeName + ", " + assemblyName);
    }
}
```

And the process to deserialize is changed to this:

```
//runtimeTypes is a Type[] with all the runtime generated types, data is the serialized string

JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All, Binder = new binder( runtimeTypes ) };

var deser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <BaseElement[]>(data, settings);
```

Hope it helps someone in my same situation.

Cheers